# Can Gimbal lock occur with extrinsic Euler angles?

Tags: linear-algebra

The gimbal lock seems to be considered with local coordinates (if I read most of the materials correctly). However, according to the matrix calculation, the final rotation matrix (RxRyRz) is (from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)):

[image]

The whole calculation process doesn't show any assumption to the reference frame, which alpha and gamma as Euler angles can also be considered as world (extrinsic) reference frame.

My question is: is Gimbal lock generally happens no matter which coordinate frame is chosen?

Comment: As Wikipedia says, your final matrix seems to show that gimbal lock _does_ occur here ($\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are 'locked' together).  Also, the physical phenomenon of gimbal lock is a physical thing, that doesn't know, and so can't change according to, in which coördinates it is measured.  So I think I don't understand the question.

Comment: @LSpice Did you mean you could not understand my question or you don't know the answer to the question? The final matrix indeed shows an arbitrary point (x, y, z) will land in (z, ..., ...), which indeed is a gimbal lock phenomenon. But the overall calculation didn't assume in which way to represent \alpha, \beta \gamma. This seems to suggest that the reference frame can be an arbitrary one. Am I understand correctly?

Comment: yes, the reference frame is arbitrary.

Comment: @LSpice: I would say G.L. is (in accordance with the answer by BS. below) an intrinsic geometric phenomenon, rather than a physical one, in the sense that it involves a change of manifold by which you parametrize angles but doesn't affect the trajectory of motion that you may define using angles described by one manifold or the other. But that's probably just "semantics".

Comment: @Qfwfq, as you [say](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359155/can-gimbal-lock-occur-with-extrinsic-euler-angles#comment904163_359155), it's just semantics.  There is certainly a genuine mathematical phenomenon here, but it's reflecting a *physical* phenomenon (as @‍BS. [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/a/359233) in the sentence beginning "Mechanically …"), and so has to show up no matter what mathematics is used to model the physics.  At least, I think so ….

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I don't understand why you vote the question off-topic. Can you recommend somewhere else that I can ask? So far I think this is a mathematical question other than a physical question.

Comment: as I understand it, Gimbal Lock involves the case of an intrinsic mathematical singularity (1 axis with a 90 degree rotation) applied iteratively, so I don't believe this question should be closed as it's about the **mathematical cause** of Gimbal Lock... extrinsic application is non-iterative, so in theory it should avoid Gimbal Lock, but I'm no mathematician.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gimbal lock as I understand it is the fact that when you parameterize the group of rotations $SO(3)$ by three angles (Euler's, or any other of your choice), the corresponding map from the 3-dimensional torus $T^3=(R/2\pi Z)^3$ to $SO(3)$ has to have a non-surjective differential at some point of the torus, i.e. for some angles.
Mechanically, this means that you cannot move easily to all closely neighbouring rotations : you have to change angles by at least $c \sqrt{\epsilon}$ in total to effect some rotations which are only $\epsilon$ away.

The reason is topological : A non-gimbal-locking parameterization $T^3\to SO(3)$ would be a local diffeomorphism, hence a [covering map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) by compactness.

This is impossible because the [universal covering space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Universal_covers) of $SO(3)$ is the sphere $S^3$ of quaternions (the origin of the so-called belt trick), whereas that of $T^3$ is $R^3$.